# divide value of next row and create column in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one csv like

```
id,value
1,100
1,150
1,200
1,250
2,300
2,350
2,400
2,450
```

I want to generate one column based on value of each of the unique id.

For Example:

- first 2 rows for id 1 has value 100, 150
- i am trying to create column `raise` which will divide value like this
- 100/100 = 1 so first row with in raise column will have 1
- 150/100 = 1.5 so second row with in raise column will have 2
- same for id 2
- 250/250 = 1 and 300/250 = 1.166

> I took 100 because its the first value for that `id`, same for the 2nd 'id'
>   for example:

```
id,value
1,150
1,100
1,200
1,250
```

if this was the case then output should be

```
id,value,raise
1,150,150/150
1,100,100/150
1,200,200/150
1,250,250/150
```

so in the end my output will be like

```
   id  value  raise
0   1    100  1.000
1   1    150  1.500
2   1    200  2.000
3   1    250  2.500
4   2    300  1.000
5   2    350  1.166
6   2    400  1.333
7   2    450  1.500
```

I don't know how to create it except using for loop through all the `id`.

> Not all the value has same interval it's just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide column by `Series` created by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['raise'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('first'))
print (df)
   id  value     raise
0   1    100  1.000000
1   1    150  1.500000
2   1    200  2.000000
3   1    250  2.500000
4   2    300  1.000000
5   2    350  1.166667
6   2    400  1.333333
7   2    550  1.833333
```