# Cumulative Division in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to look for a way to implement a "cumulative division" function for my dataframe. Since there is only cumsum, cummax etc, but no "cumdiv", is there any way to manually make one "cumulative division" function up?

I saw this question [divide value of next row and create column in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54516421/11872408) but it did not work for me. The resultant column just had a value of 1 for all rows.

I should note that the accepted answer for the question that I linked is similar to the result I want, just that instead of the bottom index being divided by the upper index, I want it the other way around, where the bottom index is being divided by the upper index. This will continue until the end of the index.

```
    Median ($)
Year    
2009    2792
2010    2991
2011    3121
2012    3232
2013    3204
2014    3339
2015    3419
2016    3470
2017    3537
2018    3588
```

I am trying to make it such that the median salary for 2009 is divided by the salary for the subsequent years. So 2009's salary is divided by 2010, and the percentage is shown in a new column. This repeats for 2011 and so on.

Hope I am making a clearer picture.

Comment: could you, for clarification, add input and desired output. This would make things clearer and self contained. Plus, we would have data to play with

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Hi there, I made some edits, hopefully it paints a clearer picture.

Comment: so there is nothing cumulative in here, right? it's just: divide everything by first row?

Comment: Anyway, sample output would help to clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
df['Median ($)'].divide(df.Median.iloc[0])
```

which gives

```
Year
2009    1.000000
2010    1.071275
2011    1.117837
2012    1.157593
2013    1.147564
2014    1.195917
2015    1.224570
2016    1.242837
2017    1.266834
2018    1.285100
Name: Median, dtype: float64
```

now it's all about formatting, i.e you could subtract 1 and multiply by 100 etc. Depends on the precise task

Comment: well shucks. the code is that simple. Just wondering, if I wanted to keep the column title as Median ($), how should I go about it. I got a syntax error for having ($).

Comment: Ah, by the way, I am thankful for your answer. Really a big help for me.

Comment: You can just access that column via `df['Median($)']` instead of `df.Median`. The whitespace prevents you from using the .dot-accessor here

Answer (score 1):

So, a first guess, and what I would think could be a cumdiv functions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"vals": [10, 3, 2]})
df = df.assign(logged=lambda x: np.log(x.vals))
df.loc[1:,"logged"] *= -1
df["logs_cummulated"] = df.logged.cumsum()
df["cumdiv"] = np.exp(df.logs_cummulated)
df

   vals    logged  logs_cummulated     cumdiv
0    10  2.302585         2.302585  10.000000
1     3 -1.098612         1.203973   3.333333
2     2 -0.693147         0.510826   1.666667
```

Note that under logarithms: `log(x/y) = log(x) - log(y)` hence you can transform division into subtraction (a form of addition).  Multiply the logged column by -1 after the first row, since those rows are on the right side of the logarithm identity shown above. Then you can cumulatively add the transformed logged column (i.e use`cumsum`) and afterwards you just need to exponentiate back again.

Btw, if you don't multiply by -1 you'll obtain cumulative multiplication.

Comment: **hence you can transform division into subtraction (a form of addition)** Could you elaborate on how this is a form of addition?

Comment: I mean, if I want to compute `a - b` this is the same as `a + ((-1)*b)` so subtraction is in fact addition with a slight modification